# Are Safari & Mobile Safari rendering rounded borders with radius and padding incorrectly?

Tags: safari, mobile-safari, padding, css

Safari and Mobile Safari seem to have a problem when you combine border radius, padding and borders. Works fine in Chrome and Firefox.

[image: Expected Outcome] <-- Expected

[image: Safari Rendering] <-- Safari Rendering

HTML:

```
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/animals/3/" />
```

CSS:

```
img {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 500px;
    -moz-border-radius:    500px;
    border-radius:         500px;
    padding: 3px;
    border: 1px solid #999;
    margin: 10px
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/ucNwx/2/

Is it my fault or Safaris? How would I fix it?

Comment: Removing the padding seems to fix the inner whitespace. Why the `500px` border-radius?

Comment: Is something wrong with a border radius of 50%?  http://jsfiddle.net/ucNwx/3/

Comment: @Mooseman Yeah but I *want* that padding for the border effect :) High border-radius is there to create a circle

Comment: @cimmanon thanks, that's a better way to create circles :)

Comment: @eteubert Right, but it seems that it renders without taking the `border-radius` into consideration. Not sure if this is a bug from an older version of WebKit...

Comment: Chrome 24: WebKit 537.17; Safari 5.1.7: WebKit 534.57.2

Comment: @eteubert: Did you report this as a bug?

Comment: This bug still exists in Safari Version 6.0.4

Answer (score 10, accepted):

My bet it's Safari bug: `border-radius` is applied late and produces clipping effect. Fortunately, `box-shadow` is rendered correctly, so let's use it:

```
border-radius: 50%;
box-shadow:
  0 0 0 3px white,
  0 0 0 4px #999;
```

[Works](http://jsfiddle.net/ucNwx/12/) on Safari 6 on iPad and OS X.

Comment: Nice! There are still rendering issues in OS X Safari but Mobile Safari renders nicely now.

Answer (score 2):

Best solution I can think of right now: http://jsfiddle.net/ucNwx/5/

Uses a wrapper div to draw the border and then places the image inside of it. Still got some artifacts on the right edge but I guess that's a Safari bug.

[image]

HTML

```
<div class="border-container">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/animals/3/" />
</div>
```

CSS

```
.border-container {
    width: 206px;
    height: 206px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    -moz-border-radius:    50%;
    border-radius:         50%;
    border: 1px solid #999;
    margin: 10px
}

img {
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    -moz-border-radius:    50%;
    border-radius:         50%;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 3px;
}
```