# <img> was clipped by 1px on mobile safari

Tags: ios, css, mobile, safari

JSBin: https://jsfiddle.net/mnLw83ga/

Whether it was zoomed or not, the image was clipped by 1px on the top. It will return normal when the phone was in horizontal mode.

code :

```css
img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://www.duoziwang.com/uploads/1602/1-160221222J70-L.jpg" alt="">
```

Sometimes the clip happened on the bottom, when zooming.

It looked like this:

safari image border-radius bug
[image: safari image border-radius bug]

Device Info: iOS 10.3.1 iPhone 6
Cannot recurrent on my iPhone 7

Comment: how about, instead of border-radius directly to img element, do it to the wrapper. like this https://jsfiddle.net/yknok9nz/1/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are Safari & Mobile Safari rendering rounded borders with radius and padding incorrectly?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14444806/are-safari-mobile-safari-rendering-rounded-borders-with-radius-and-padding-inc)

Comment: Both comments above did not solve my problem. the clipping still exists.

Answer (score 0):

The clipping in Safari may be due to the version of Safari you're using. In Safari percentage values for `border-radius`are only supported in 5.1+. I'd hate to think that that's the case with your version, however, it's possible. But on my end (Safari 11.0.2) it's coming through without clipping.

The safety would be to switch out the percentage for a fixed `border-radius` of `50px` since your width and height are fixed.

```css
img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50px;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://www.duoziwang.com/uploads/1602/1-160221222J70-L.jpg" alt="">
```